# Framework auto migrations

Tags: django

In Django (and some other frameworks) there is auto migration generation functionality:

```
For example I create a class:

class User(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

And with some command you can create migrations:

So if you delete the row date_joined for example and run the command it will drop the column.

I want to ask if it is possible to rename the column without manually creating migration.

If I want to rename "date_joined" to "date_registered".

Yes, the framework doesn't know whether it should rename the column or drop and add a new one.

So my question is is there solution clever solution that would not need to create manually creating the migrations or it can be done automatically with minimum coding.

I need only an idea or pseude code, not code.

Thanks

Comment: How would you determine (automatically) that a change is an alter column instead of a drop column + add column by just looking at the model code? It doesn't seem to retain enough information...?

Comment: Yes, correct. I thought i can save property in the field that it is renamed, but i should save all renames and it gets very complicated - i should save all previous renames for the column in order not to generate SQL errors.

Comment: Alternatively, (and quite outside of Django), you could store a unique identifier with each field, e.g. `date_joined = DateField(fieldid=42, name="date_joined")` and then you'd know that it is a rename if the fieldid is the same and the name is different...

Comment: Actually django intelligently detects a simple renaiming of a field and asks you if your renamed it, when runnung the `makemigrations` mangement command. If you answer `yes` it will just rename the colunm instead of creating a new one. But the algorithm can get confused if you alter other things on a model too and assume it is a new field.

Comment: This is good idea, but if i rename the field twice and dont run the migration, it will not know which column to rename, so maybe i should store the rename history but it will get very complicated and large quickly i guess.